# Is there a relevance of MouseMove event in the context of touch devices

Tags: c#

I recently developed a logger application in which I experimented opening of my custom menus on mousehover. My custom menu doesn't derive from Microsoft menu. Now my logger application works fine while using mouse but when used on touch device like tablet menu opening does happen only on finger tapping. So I am just wondering if a touching an area by finger is equal to mouse click why not hovering a finger can not be deemed and treated as MouseMove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because we are not quite there yet. A hovering finger doesn't get detected by touchscreens. Microsoft is working on a way to make that happen however: http://www.androidauthority.com/microsoft-pre-touch-690379/

Comment: Aren't we familiar with motion detection sensors in CCTV or heat signature change in modern days electronic devices? Whats so different here that keeping us reaching there?

Comment: I am glad my thought was not ridiculous since someone is already working hard on achieving that. Thanks a lot to let me know about this.